# Majuscule dans la transcription des indicateurs patronymiques des noms arabes

Tags: typographie, noms-propres, majuscules, arabe, noms-de-famille

J’entends par *indicateur patronymique* les mots comme *ibn*|*bani* (littéralement « fils de ») et *ab[û|i]* (littéralement « père de »).

L’usage chez les anciens arabes, quelque peut perpétué aujourd’hui encore, voudrait que l’on nomme certaines personnes par le prénom de leur père ou, au contraire, de leur fils comme [Bilāl *ibn* Rabbah](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilal_ibn_Rabah) (Bilāl *fils de* Rabbah*), [*Abu* Huraira](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Huraira) (*Père de* Houraira) ou encore [Ali *ibn Abi* Talib](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_ibn_Abi_Talib) (Ali *fils du père de* Talib, forme qui peut sembler cocasse mais au demeurant très courante).

Simplement, je me demande si, en vertu des [règles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nom_propre#Nom_propre_et_majuscule) typographiques portant sur le nom propre, on devait utiliser les majuscules au début de ces indicateurs patronymiques. Car, à dire vrais, dans « Abu Huraira », le nom propre est « Huraira », *abu* n’étant qu’un nom commun. À la rigueur, on pourrait mettre une majuscule en début du nom, que ce soit le noyau du nom propre ou un indicateur patronymique, mais pour le cas où ces derniers se trouvent en milieu de nom propre, que faire ?
Dans « Bilāl *ibn* Rabbah », tous les noms propres *stricto sensu* ont une majuscule et *ibn*, le nom commun qui ne se trouve pas en début de « titre » n’en a pas. Tout est en ordre.

Sauf, là encore, que j’ai souvent vu « Ali *ibn **A**bi* Talib » (« Ali *fils du **P**ère de* Talib »). *Abi* a une majuscule mais pas *ibn* alors que les deux sont en position médiane. Quoi penser ? Ma théorie est que « Abi Talib » (« Père de Talib ») est en soit un « titre » à part entière avec ses propres règles qui se trouve imbriqué dans un autre titre. Or, comme dans le titre « Abi Talib », *abi*, bien que nom commun, se trouve en début et doit comporter une majuscule. Majuscule qui donc demeure lorsque ce titre est imbriqué dans un autre titre.

Mais est-ce bien là le bon usage ?

Comment: Cf. http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particule_%28onomastique%29 , après vérification, 'ibn' signifie fils et pas 'de' génitif, donc c'est encore plus flou. D’après wikipedia, il semble que pour les naturalisés français, la personne peut choisir de mettre la particule en majuscule ou pas. C'est donc un peu au choix.

Comment: Je me suis mal fait comprendre. Dans ma traduction, j’ai utilisé *de* comme un véritable adjectif possessif et non comme particule nobiliaire. Le fait est qu’en arabe on n’utilise pas de tel adjectif, la possessivité étant exprimée par la place des mots « fils Hamza » se comprends « fils *de* Hamza ». Nécessairement, en voulant traduire littérairement et non littéralement, il fallait respecter les contraintes grammaticales de la langue d’arrivée et donc d’ajouter un *de*.

Comment: Oui. Je n'ai pas de réponse précise, c'est pour ça que j'ai juste laissé un commentaire. Les indications patronymiques sont nombreuses en langues étrangères, (Mac, O', -vskii, -vna, tous fils de), ainsi que les indications d'appartenance familiale (de, Di, von, van, ...) ou générationnel (3eme du nom, possible aux US ou au Japon). Le deuxième cas en français est bien délimité, il faut utiliser l'orthographe et la casse de la langue source, sauf pour le naturalisés qui font ce qu'ils veulent, dixit wikipedia.

Comment: Mais la langue arabe n'a pas d'alphabet mais un abugida (voyelles en exposant?), et de plus tu dis qu'elle n'exprime pas le génitif par une particule explicite. Il me semble d’après ce que tu dis que 'ibn' soit utilisé comme particule d'appartenance familiale (de,...) d’où la minuscule, et que Abu soit en majuscule par déférence. Pas une réponse en bonnet difforme donc, mais d’expérience avec les scripts non latins, c'est un peu le bordel (voir toutes les transcriptions possibles des langues asiatiques). A mon avis, a part naturalisation qui fige l'usage, c'est libre si c'est cohérent.

Comment: pardon, bonnet difforme, référence a Coluche, mais pas classe sur un forum de langue française.

Comment: La difficulté par rapport aux usages slaves (*-off*|*-ova*) ou des celtiques (*Mac-*) est que l’arabe n’utilise pas d’affixe mais dit explicitement « Untel fils de Tel autre ».
L’arabe utilise effectivement un *abjad* qui note les voyelles en diacritique mais celà ne nous importe pas.
J’ai aussi pensé à la déférence pour *Abu* mais il me faut encore une certitude :/

Comment: @user5628 La référence (prestigieuse) à l'un des forgerons de notre langue actuelle ne peut pas être péjorative, tu peux en être fier comme si tu avais un bar-tabac ;-)

Comment: Je ne peux pas me prononcer sur la raison, mais l'ONU a des [règles précises](http://dd.dgacm.org/ores/french/capitalization.htm) en la matière - cherchez "arabe" dans le lien.

Comment: Selon le lien de Yellows, nous connaissons les usages de l’ONU concernant *ibn* et *bin*. Mais le document n’est pas explicite au sujet d’*abou*. :/

Answer (score 2):

C'est une remarque qui porte sur votre question plus qu'une réponse, mais dans le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale* (édition 2002), à propos d'imbrication, on trouve p. 26 deux exemples qui semblent accréditer votre hypothèse :

> - Ibn Saoud ;
> - Youssouf ibn Tachfin.